# Strange response from the mandrill server

Tags: django, mandrill

I have a django app and I use mandrill for mails sending. 
    Till recently, I was sending simple mails and it was working great. 
    But now, I want to send mails with attachments, so I changed my message 
    construction to this:

```
def construct_message(self):
        content = self.get_content()
        attachments = self.kwargs.get('attachments', None)
        message = {} if not attachments else MIMEMultipart()
        message['subject'] = content['subject']
        message['text'] = content['txt']
        message['html'] = content['html']
        message['from_email'] = self.sender
        message['from_name'] = '***'
        recipients = self._get_recipients()
        if attachments:
            message['to'] = ", ".join([r["email"] for r in recipients])
        else:
            message['to'] = recipients
        message['cc'] = []
        message['bcc'] = []
        if attachments:
            for a in attachments:
                part = MIMEApplication(open(a,"rb").read())
                Encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(a))
                message.attach(part)
            message = message.as_string()
        return message

def send_message(self, message):
        """Actually send the message."""
        api_key = settings.MANDRILL_API_KEY_INTERNAL if self.is_internal else settings.MANDRILL_API_KEY_EXTERNAL
        key_type_str = "internal" if self.is_internal else "external"
        logging.debug("Sending mail through %s API key %s" % (key_type_str, api_key))
        mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(api_key)
        return mandrill_client.messages.send(message=message)
```

And since then, I get the following response from mandrill API call:

**ValidationError: Validation error: {"message":"Please enter an array"}**

Do you have an idea, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks, Alex A.

Comment: Where do you call `send_message`?

Comment: In the __init__ of my Notification class:  def __init__(self, recipients, notification_type=None, sender=None, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.send_message(self.construct_message())